# How to write a condition to define a variable one time in C++

Tags: c++, variables

I am writing a function that is called every cycle. In this function I define a variable

```
bool forceDisplacementLaw(ContactModelMechanicalState *state) {
bool max_check = false
//something here
if ((nsmax >= pbProps_->pb_ten_)) {
    max_check = true;
}
}
```

`max_check` will be changed to `true` now in my function and I want to keep it true forever. However, I define `max_check` at the beginning of the code and it is initialized to `false` again.

Is there any way to keep it true when it turn to `true` permanently?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it is unclear what you are referring to

Comment: On second thought, are you familiar with static variables? If not, please refer to a good C++ book asap.

Comment: @StoryTeller: thank you, I will check it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define it as a static.

```
 bool firstTime(){   
      static bool bOne = true;
      bool bRet = bOne;  
      bOne = false;   
      return bRet; 
  }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Static variables are your friend when keeping track of data inside functions between calls. Global variables are just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I think StoryTeller got you right. Consider

```
int f()
{
    static int timesCalled = 0;
    timesCalled++;

    cout << "f has been called " << timesCalled << " times.\n";
    // actual work goes here
}
```

`timesCalled` will be initialized to 0 when f is called first and after that retain its value betwen increments (yes, the initialization is only performed once, despite appearance!)

Answer (score -1):

Use a static local variable. Static variables keep their values between function calls:

```
bool forceDisplacementLaw(ContactModelMechanicalState *state) {
    static bool max_check = false;
    //something here
    if ((nsmax >= pbProps_->pb_ten_)) {
        max_check = true;
    }
}
```

Or use a global variable instead:

```
static bool max_check = true;
//...
bool forceDisplacementLaw(ContactModelMechanicalState *state) {
    //something here
    if ((nsmax >= pbProps_->pb_ten_)) {
        max_check = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not suggest dubious practices in answers. A global variable (with extarnal linkage, no less) is a very very bad idea.